# PHP SDK + Javascript SDK problems in Internet Explorer

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

When using PHP SDK + Javascript SDK (for apprequests) Internet Explorer
(version 9 - I also tried in 7 and also has problems with endless refreshing)
is showing error all the time "To display the webpage again, the web browser
needs to resend the information you've previously submited...". Clicking retry
just displays the same message again. If "FB.init" is removed from code, app
works (but without apprequests,...).

You can test this bug here: http://apps.facebook.com/testing-bugs/

Or get the code which is used for this app (it is basically same as in SDK
example) - http://www.mediafire.com/?y1314p8lz21krfd

Just change those two in index.php:

```
'appId' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
'secret' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
```

Is there any fix for this or...?

Answer (score 0):

the code you are using for testing is for the **facebook connect** and you are using the **facebook app**. So download the code from below url and try this one:

https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk

Comment: I am using this code from github.com/facebook/php-sdk Along PHP SDK I need also Javascript SDK (for apprequests).

Comment: you can find the js-sdk example from here: https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/examples/with_js_sdk.php

Answer (score 0):

you should go to this site http://www.fbrell.com/ and see how he does it, I think he is doing what you are trying to do.